# Intellij IDEA, java and remote development

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, raspberry-pi2

How to configure Intellij IDEA for compile my java-application on remote machine?
In netbeans I can configure it easily and remote development works perfectly but in Intellij IDEA I can't understand how to do it. 
I searched for an answer in the NET and I can't find it. All answers are for Web remote/deployment only.
I need it because I use java + raspberry Pi + pi4j.
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's currently not possible. If I remember correctly, it is possible in other JetBrains IDE's like PhpStorm. But not in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

You can add, new deployment configuration via (IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.5  Ultimate): 
[Tools] -> [Deployment] -> [Configuration]

Comment: and so what ? I configured this option, but it does not work.

Comment: I think IntelliJ doesn't support remote compile, you can compile project at own machine and send results to your remote by upload options.

Comment: I can't compile project on my own machine, because my machine has different OS with remote machine. Library pi4j only for linux.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Setting this option only configures synchronization of files between the development and deployment machines.